# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Expatriates Stack Exchange](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Does working abroad for US clients qualify one for the "foreign earned income exclusion" via the "physical presence test"?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2734/does-working-abroad-for-us-clients-qualify-one-for-the-foreign-earned-income-ex)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can I take the theory exam in English for driving license in Portugal?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2710/can-i-take-the-theory-exam-in-english-for-driving-license-in-portugal)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Going to USA from France with my girlfriend](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/going-to-usa-from-france-with-my-girlfriend)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Private visa agency in Thailand](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/private-visa-agency-in-thailand)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Can I apply for a secured credit card in the USA as a non-resident (currently adjusting status)?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/can-i-apply-for-a-secured-credit-card-in-the-usa-as-a-non-resident-currently-ad)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Taxes and Health Insurance (US -> UK, paid by US Govt)](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/taxes-and-health-insurance-us-uk-paid-by-us-govt)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Are Turkey's customs fees for international mail high?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/are-turkeys-customs-fees-for-international-mail-high)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What is the impact if I change my H1B VISA sponsor while my wife is at Home Country?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/what-is-the-impact-if-i-change-my-h1b-visa-sponsor-while-my-wife-is-at-home-coun)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Japanese Spouse Applying for UK Indefinite Leave to Remain - Koseki Tohon or Marriage Certificate?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/japanese-spouse-applying-for-uk-indefinite-leave-to-remain-koseki-tohon-or-mar)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Living expenses in Abu Dhabi, for a moderate lifestyle](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/living-expenses-in-abu-dhabi-for-a-moderate-lifestyle)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the questions with a positive net score have answers with quotes from a relevant official website and I think this reflects what I think of as a well researched answer. Some of the questions with negative net scores have highly voted answers that seem like they could be supported by links to official documentation. It would be nice if we could bring up the quality of those answers. Maybe through comments, community edits, or even bounties.